# Gtkmm : How to catch right click signal for a Gtk::Table?

Tags: pygtk, gtk, gtk#, gtkmm

I'm making an app using GTKMM and I want to know how to catch the right click signal from a Gtk::Table ?

And also how to catch if the Mouse is over a Gtk::Table ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok I figured out the solution. I was able to capute the right click by overiding the button press event :

```
virtual bool on_button_press_event(GdkEventButton* event);
```

Comment: wasn't unwind who gave you the solution?

Comment: Your answer repeats the same as unwind already mentioned. Can you elaborate, especially on how to get _right_-click, plus catch mouse-over? I have similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

All GTK+ widgets have the [button-press-event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) and [focus-in-event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-in-event) events. You can use the latter, in combination with its complement ([focus-out-event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-out-event)) to track if the mouse is inside the widget.

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can do that, sorry i'm new to GTK programming.

I have a Window, which has a table inside. So I believe for the window I need to enable the GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK mask? How do i do that? and then how do I connect the focus-out-event with my table?

Thanks.

Comment: In my window's constructor I called the function: set_events(Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

And In my Table constructor I connected the signal:
   signal_button_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&myTableClass::on_right_click));


bool myTableClass::on_right_click(GdkEventButton* event);


However this does not catch the right click.